# Push Notification In React Native

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification

I am integrating push notification in react native with help of "react-native-push-notification" library. The push is coming from node js(backend).
I am successfully getting push in both environment Android and IOS.

Now i have two issues
1) In ios when i am getting push there is one parameter in notification payload "userInteraction". This parameter is for that user clicked the notification or not. Now it is working fine in android but in ios this is always false.
2)I want to set custom image in push notification, which is coming from push.

I am using "https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification" this library.

I have tried this code :-

```
  export function setupPushNotification(handleNotification) {
    PushNotification.configure({

    onRegister: function (token) {

        if (Platform.OS == 'ios') {
            firebase.messaging().getToken().then((token) => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(token))
                requestaddAuthToke(token)
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("hello2 " + JSON.stringify(data))
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("hello3 " + JSON.stringify(error.message));
            })
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log("hello2 " + JSON.stringify(token.token))
            requestaddAuthToke(token.token)
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("hello2 " + JSON.stringify(data))
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("hello3 " + JSON.stringify(error.message));
            })
        }
    },

    onNotification: function (notification) {
        const clicked = notification.userInteraction;
        if (clicked)
            handleNotification(notification.episodeCode)

        if (Platform.OS == 'ios')
            notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);

    },

    senderID: "529815244511",
    permissions: {
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true
    },



    popInitialNotification: true,
    requestPermissions: true,


 })

  return PushNotification
}
```

Any type of help will appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using react-native-push-notification and react-native-one-signal both at the same time. The only issue is onNotification not called when tapped on local notification in iOS only.

For a solution :

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/919#issuecomment-439373380